# MongoMapper default callback

Tags: mongomapper

I'd like to define a default `before_save` callback for any model that is a MongoMapper model. For example, with ActiveRecord I could just do this in an initializer:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    before_save :strip_attrs

    private

    def strip_attrs
      # do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Is it possible to do something like this with MongoMapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building an [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) plugin and then plug it into MongoMapper::Document, just like [MongoMapper does](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper/document.rb) for its internal plugins.

```
module StripOnSave
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :strip_attrs
  end

  def strip_attrs
    # ...
  end
end

module MongoMapper
  module Document
    include StripOnSave
  end

  module EmbeddedDocument
    include StripOnSave
  end
end
```